# Вопрос по работе группирующих скобок в регулярном выражении

Tags: python, python-3.x, регулярные-выражения

Имеются строки состоящие вперемешку из хэштэгов и других символов.
Мне необходимо поделить парами символы и хэштэги, идущие за ними.
Пример:
есть строка `'abc####d##c#'` Я написал вот такое вот:

```
import re
def clean_string(s):
    string = re.findall(r'(\w+)(#+)', s)
    return string
```

На выходе получаю кортежи : `[('abc', '####'), ('d', '##'), ('c', '#')]`

Но, к сожалению, это не работает если последний символ не хэштэг. Тогда последней пары просто не получается.
Я совершенно нулячий в регулярках. Подскажите, пожалуйста, можно ли сделать как-то, чтобы если последнему символу уже не хватает хэштэга, то вместо него парой добавлялся какой-нибудь символ? Что-то типа как в `itertools.zip_longest`.

Comment: `Но, к сожалению, это не работает если последний символ не хэштэг. Тогда последней пары просто не получается.` - а можно пример, что именно получаете и что ожидаете? Жедательно прмо в тексте вопроса

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Используйте `*` вместо `+`:

```
import re

def clean_string(s):
    s1 = re.findall(r'(\w+)(#*)', s)
    return s1

print(clean_string('abc####d##c#'))
print(clean_string('abc####d##c'))
```

Comment: Та за шо минус?